# No class weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.BinaryPatternsPyramidFilter can be located on the Java class path

Tags: java, weka

I'm using following package for calling Weka functions from within Matlab https://github.com/NicholasMcCarthy/wekalab

and my code is

```
close all; clear all; clc;
dbstop if error

 %%
 javaclasspath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-8\weka.jar');
 javaaddpath('C:\Users\PC\wekafiles\packages\imageFilters\imageFilters.jar'); 

 %%
 import weka.filters.*
 import weka.filters.Filter.*
 import weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.*
 import weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.BinaryPatternsPyramidFilter.*
 import weka.classifiers.Classifier.*
 import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.*
 import weka.classifiers.Evaluation.*
 import weka.core.Attribute.*
 import weka.core.FastVector.*
 import weka.core.Instances.*
 import weka.core.DenseInstance.*
 import weka.classifiers.Classifier.*
 import weka.classifiers.Evaluation.*
 import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.*
 import weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.*
 import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.*;

  D = wekaLoadData('E:\pro\program\selectedPics\character\test.arff', 'ARFF');

  myFilter = wekaFilter('weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.BinaryPatternsPyramidFilter');

  filteredData = wekaApplyFilter(D, myFilter);
```

when i use the default filters of weka,

```
myFilter = wekaFilter('weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Standardize');
```

it works fine but when i use the installed package of weka (imageFilters) it give me this error

```
Error using javaObject
```

*No class weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.BinaryPatternsPyramidFilter can be located on the Java class path*

**image filter (package) path:** C:\Users\PC\wekafiles\packages\imageFilters

**weka path:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-8

Environment variable & their paths:

CLASSPATH

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-8\weka.jar; 
>   C:\Program Files(x86)\Weka-3-8\imageFilters\imageFilters.jar;
>   C:\Users\PC\wekafiles\packages\imageFilters\src\main\java; 
>   C:\Users\PC\wekafiles\packages\imageFilters\src\main\java\filters\unsupervised\instance\imagefilter;
>   C:\Users\PC\wekafiles\packages\imageFilters\src\main\java\filters\unsupervised\instance;

java

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;

PATH

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;

PATH_HOME

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **weka.Run** in order to use additional packages in weka ([weka.Run details](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/Run.html))

On the Terminal:

Before using it you may want to add your weka.jar file into CLASSPATH:

```
export CLASSPATH=path_to_weka.jar
```

For example, a way to use this command:

```
java weka.Run weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.imagefilter.BinaryPatternsPyramidFilter -D "directory were files to filter are located" -i "input arff" -o "output arff"
```

For more info, check: [Weka official documenation](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/documentation.html)

In my case, I used the manual for [Weka 3-7-8](https://ayera.dl.sourceforge.net/project/weka/documentation/3.7.x/WekaManual-3-7-8.pdf). The information mentioned is on the page 26 under *Running installed learning algorithms*. This could change from version to version.

Here you have a list of any manual you could need: [Weka manuals for every version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/documentation/)

About using it on Java, I don't have information about it. I wanted to answer this question because there might be people out there needing help with command line Weka.